# How to remove even integers from a list in Python? My function is still returning even numbers

Tags: python, arrays, list, modulo

I am having some trouble while removing even integers from a list in Python. This is what I am trying to do but I can't figure out what am I doing wrong. Is the array skipping elements due to items being removed? I would really appreciate some help.

```
def removeEven(l):
for e in l:
    if e % 2 == 0:
        l.remove(e)
print(l)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it

Answer (score 0):

Try filter:

```py
def removeEvent(l):
    return list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, l))
print(removeEvent(l))
```

Or even better:

```py
print(list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, l)))
```